# Does target structure affect neural network performance?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN to control a vehicle within a video game. The network takes a screenshot as input and uses controller values as targets. For now I'm just using two controller values as targets: steering which is a value between -1 and 1, as well as throttle, which is between 0 and 1. I have rounded the values of steering into 7 values, and throttle into 4 values giving me 28 distinct classes which I will balance (reason for rounding was difficulty balancing un-binned classes).

My question is whether I should train the network with a single value target 1-27 (one for each case), or whether I should use the two rounded controller values as targets (an array: [steering, throttle])? I understand that both create 28 target classes, but does the structure of the target output affect the performance of the network? Is one of these options noticeably better than the other?

The model for preliminary testing:

'''

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(24, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape= INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(Conv2D(36, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1164, activation='relu'))
drop_out = 1 - keep_prob
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(Dense(OUT_SHAPE, activation='softsign'))
```

'''